# Does mentula ("penis") derive from the same root as mens ("mind"), and if so why?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology, word-comparison, proto-indo-european, profanity

The Latin word *mentula* isn't properly defined in the [Lewis & Short dictionary](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmentula), but it does show up on [Latin-Dictionary.net](http://latin-dictionary.net/search/latin/mentula) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mentula#Noun_2). Both those dictionaries define *mentula* as "penis". But what's striking about this word is its resemblance to *mens, mentis*, which means "mind".

Are the two words related? Is *mentula* a diminutive of *mens*, as Wiktionary suggests? Are the two words descended from the same PIE root?

If indeed the two words are related, do we know why?

Comment: Ahem. Perhaps because the penis seems to have a mind of its own, at least at times?  This is pure conjecture on my part.

Comment: @Gordon That was my conjecture too. The Romans knew what it meant to think with your penis!

Comment: @ktm5142 I am not a Latin scholar (I am a pure beginner using Gwynne's), but some things don't seem to change with time!

Comment: And how was mentula formed then, morphologically, under your hypothesis? (Answer to your question: **very** unlikely).

Comment: @AlexB. It's not his hypothesis. It's the first suggestion in Wikipedia's article on "Latin profanity". Unsourced, natch.

Comment: I don’t use Wikipedia for etymological research.

Comment: Just to add my two cents (as I wrote my MA thesis on Roman sexuality): Strictly speaking _mentula_ does not mean ‘penis’; it means ‘cock’, ‘dick’ or similar vulgarisms. As Adams notes in _The Latin Sexual Vocabulary_ (Duckworth, 1982: 9): ‘The basic obscenity for the male organ was *mentula*.’ *Mentula* is obscene, equivalent to *cunnus*; Cicero will not use it openly even when discussing obsceneties; and so, if in need of a ‘proper’ word for penis, one would use *verpa* (Adams 1982: 12f). In Greek, μύκης and κέρας worked as polite terms equivalent to ‘penis’ (Adams 1982: 11).

Answer (score 15):

Well, this may obviously be outdated, but [G.M. Messing](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q27887651) banged out a 3-page treatment of "The Etymology of Lat. *Mentula*" for the Oct. 1956 *Classical Philology* (Vol. 51, No. 4, pp. 247–249).

---

His review of the scholarship to that point was

> **Lat. *mentula* 'membrum virile' has never been satisfactorily etymologized**. Of the various suggestions made in the past none has been endorsed wholeheartedly by the etymological dictionaries of [Walde](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q94213)-[Hofmann](http://worldcat.org/identities/lccn-n88617934/) and [Ernout](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q739986)-[Meillet](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q347001).

---

Those suggestions were

- **[Zeuss](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q76536)'s coupling it to the roots of *eminere*, *mentum*, and *mons*** (implying a sense of "arising" or "projection");
- **"Occasional" guesses of a common origin with Sanskrit [मथ्](http://sanskritdictionary.com/math/168598/1)** (*math*), emphatic मन्थ् (*manth*), a term for "spinning rapidly" that got associated with the production of fire from sticks and thus the use of friction on the human body to produce offspring; and
- **[Kretschmer](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q64431)'s analysis of *mentula* as a diminutive of *menta*** ("mint"), given a passage in Aristophanes's *Lysistrata* that supposedly uses [βληχώ](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aalphabetic+letter%3D*b%3Aentry+group%3D24%3Aentry%3Dblh%2Fxwn) ("pennyroyal", a member of the mint family) for shmekls and occasional references to mint's use as an aphrodisiac.

Against these, Ernout/Meillet finds Zeuss's derivation "unconvincing"; Kretschmer found it "unobjectionable" but insufficiently "expressive" to account for the term's popularity; and Messing concurs with them.

Messing calls the supposed relation with Sanskrit "not improbable" but hard to justify owing to "phonetic difficulties" and the lack of other close cognates in Latin.

Walde/Hofmann calls Kretschmer's derivation "almost acceptable" and Messing finds it "ingenious" before going on to note its "faulty reasoning". Closer examination of the passage in Aristophanes causes him to take the pennyroyal as the pubic hair of the Thebeian plain, not the schlongs of the Thebeian women's lovers. He offers that Kretschmer's other references to flowery cunts similarly derive from analogy to pubic hair rather than resemblance to women's anatomy. He ends by questioning mint's supposed status as an aphrodisiac as reliant on cherry-picked examples, given its usual absence from ancient discussion of such medicines.

---

Messing's own submission is based on the Grecian example provided by [E. Benveniste](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q274931)'s "Formes et Sens de Μνάομαι" in [*Sprachgeschichte und Wortbedeutung*](https://books.google.com/books?id=RmpJAAAAYAAJ) (1954, pp. 13–18). [Μνάομαι](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BC%CE%BD%CE%AC%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%B1%CE%B9) had previously been thought to consist of two homophones, one meaning "remember" or "mention" and the other meaning "woo" or "court". Benveniste established that the "second word" had actually arisen as a special figurative use of the primary sense. During that discussion, he noted how legal Latin was forced to use *mentionem facere* ("to make mention" meaning "to propose marriage") because a different derivation to *mentior* ("to think up" or "lie") disallowed Romans from turning *mentio* into a demonstrative verb. Latin similarly had to use an entirely different root (*poscere*, "to ask") for its word for "suitor".

Messing notes that Romance languages suggest an unattested low Latin **mentare* ("to mention" or "to propose"), which would have permitted **mentulus* ("dealing with proposals"). This would have then leant itself by the late Republican period to dirty jokes involving "wooing power" which explains why *mentula* isn't attested in early Latin and **is** first attested in Catullus, who preferred amusing and racy slang to straightforward vocab. **He therefore proposes that *mentula* derives from some connection with the idea of the penis acting as the "suitor", "wooer", "courter" &c. of one's beloved**. This is connected through *mentio* with the root of *mens*, but isn't a diminutive. Messing concludes:

> Naturally, I should not dare insist on all the details of the etymology just proposed, for they are pure hypothesis. Nevertheless, I think that at least the comparison of *mentula*, *sc.* 'the suitor, the wooer,' with *mentionem facere* and **mentare* is both reasonable and true to the obscenely humorous nuance which the ancients sensed in this term.

---

---

Against this, the chapter on ["*Mentula* and its Synonyms"](https://books.google.com/books?id=GDP9VHGbF1AC&pg=PA9) in **[J.N. Adams](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Noel_Adams)'s 1982 *[Latin Sexual Vocabulary](https://books.google.com/books?id=GDP9VHGbF1AC&printsec=frontcover)* repeats Martial's appeal to tradition** that *mentula* was in use at the time of King Numa and describes it as "the basic obscenity for the male organ", **"certainly... not felt by Cicero to be metaphorical" in any way**. To Cicero, it was "that word" and not dignified to write directly, even in his discussion of the lack of a diminutive for *menta*. In Adams's opinion, it's "scarcely conceivable that the spearmint stalk was so suggestive to so many people that the metaphor could have caught on in the whole community". He notes [Pokorny](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q215638) offers no etymology; refers to Ernout/Meillet's coverage of the 'prominent' and Sanskrit etymologies without noting how dismissive they are of them; and refers to [Chantraine](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2093337) for coverage of a possible connection with *mens* (Vol. III, p. 693), without discussion of its likelihood.

---

---

Ah. Found the passage in Chantraine:

> 1 μήδεα: n. pl., the male sex organ... Other forms: μέζεα..., sing..., μέδεα... Μήδεα sometimes means «urine»...
>
> *Etym*.: Obscure. It would be necessary to establish the connections between the three forms of the word. One would think that the old and vulgar form would be μέδεα, with the doublet μέζεα which supposes a gemination of δ and an aspirated pronunciation... It isn't likely that μήδεα derives from μήδομαι, although... [Spitzer](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q78739), *BSL* 40, 1939, 47 (who recalls after [Friedländer](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q91172), Lat. *mentula*, if that word derives from *mens?*). One would find more likely the hypothesis of [Wackernagel](http://www.worldcat.org/identities/lccn-n86821197/), *Spr. Unt.* 224, n. 1, who after [Nauck](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q95964), sees in μήδεα a euphemistic substitution (which goes with its presence in the [*Odyssey*]). If one searches for the etymology of μέδεα, neither μαδάω, nor μεστός is suitable. Pokorny 706, recalls Ir. *mess* (from **med-tu?*) «gland, glanded» with the original sense of «inflated», etc. But the origin of *mess* seems to be quite different...
>
> 2 μήδεα: «thoughts, worries», cf. μήδομαι.

That doesn't say much about what Adams was talking about at all, although it perhaps suggests an original derivation from Greek or its etymon, where—like British 'goolies'—an original neuter plural in reference to the testicles or whole kit eventually got used—like 'gooly'—in Latin's 1st-declension singular to refer particularly to the dick itself.

---

---

[J.T. Katz](https://scholar.princeton.edu/jtkatz/home)'s 1998 "Testimonia Ritus Italici" in *Harvard Studies in Classical Philology* (Vol. 98, pp. 183–217)—principally focused on the implications of [*testis*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/testis#Latin) meaning both "witness" and "testicle"—also mentions in passing **(1)** that the Russian words [мудрый](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9#Russian) ("wise") and [муде](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5#Russian) ("testicle") also "probably" both derive from PIE **men-* and **(2)** that [M.L. West](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q669908) argues **there was an "almost universal ancient conception according to which the marrow originates in the brain and descends from there through the spine... to become semen...**", an identity that shows up as late as Shakespeare's *All's Well that Ends Well*.

---

---

Meanwhile, in the middle of [M.L. Wagner](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q76731)'s 1907 [*Lautlehre der Südsardischen Mundarten*](https://books.google.com/books?id=f4xJAAAAYAAJ&pg=PR3) ([pp. 12–3](https://books.google.com/books?id=f4xJAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA12)), he makes cold water all over such theories by just drawing a straight line from *mentula* to [*mingere*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mingo#Latin) and [*meiere*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meio#Latin) ("to piss"), making it—and presumably also Gr. μήδεα—the equivalent of English "pisser".

---

---

Ok. That turned into a massive (albeit interesting) textwall.

**TL;DR**:

- **It's very possible that *mentula* is cognate with *mens* and derives from a PIE root involving the mind**, based on Neolithic and/or Bronze Age understandings of human anatomy; and
- It's **also** been argued that it's a lewd joke involving courtship; but
- Based on the surviving accounts and usage, **the Romans were certainly not making a lewd "little-mind-of-its-own" joke using a contemporary derivation from *mens* itself**.

Comment: Quite the textwall indeed, but, oh, what a stimulating one! Thorough research and pointed discussion, a pleasure to read. I have one formal suggestion, though: the second and third quotation blocks do not seem to be very clearly introduced; we cannot be completely sure whom you are quoting. The second block is by Messing, or is it not a quotation at all, but your own comment? The third could be Adams, but there is a double line in between, and the following paragraph suggests otherwise. Lastly, perhaps your elongated answer could benefit from thrusting the TL;DR up to the beginning.

Comment: Excellent. P.S. I apologize for my tumescent puns above.

Comment: @Cerberus At least you were warmly receptive!

Comment: @CMonsour: Always! Very warmly. I've just come home slightly tipsy.

Comment: If it originated as a diminutive of *mens*, why would we expect our sources to know this?  We're talking about the *hanc hodie* crowd here, not exactly refined scholars.

Comment: [This answer has been nominated as one of the best answers of 2020.](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/531/79) (Unfortunately this was written in 2018, making it ineligible for the prizes.)

Answer (score 1):

When the linguists have had their say we can perhaps ask the poets for their opinion, famously Goethe, mirroring the Graeco-Latin elegiac metre:

> Gib mir statt »Der Schwanz« ein ander Wort, o Priapus,
>
> Denn ich Deutscher, ich bin übel als Dichter geplagt.
>
> Griechisch nennt ich dich φαλλος das klänge doch prächtig den Ohren,
>
> Und lateinisch ist auch mentula leidlich ein Wort.
>
> Mentula käme von mens, der Schwanz ist etwas von hinten,
>
> Und nach hinten war mir niemals ein froher Genuß.